# useState not updating data when passing from parent function component using ref

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, use-state, react-forwardref

I am trying to send data to child function component where I am binding form fields with that data. It works fine on first call, but when I am calling 2nd time the data never update in state, its always shows the first one.

This is parent which use the ref of child component

```
export default function Form1() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(10);

    const AddNewRef = useRef();

    const clickMe=() => {

        setCount(count+1);
        setCounter(counter*2);

        AddNewRef.current.showDrawer(counter*2);

    }


    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked count: {count} & counter: {counter} times</p>
            {
                count > 10 ?
                (
                        <p className='red'>your count is greater then 10</p>
                ) :
                (
                    <p className='green'>your count is less then 10</p>
                )
            }
            <button onClick={() => clickMe()}>
                Click me
            </button>

           
            <AddNew ref={AddNewRef} Count={count} Counter={counter}  />

        </div>
    )
}
```

This is child component

```
const AddNew=forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const[objCounter, setobjCounter] = useState(null);

    useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
            showDrawer(count) {


              setobjCounter(count);
              //only shows at first click at parent, Not updating on 2nd, 3rd click from parent and so on....


          }
        }),
    )

return (
    <>
      <Drawer
        title={<span> <i className='fa-solid fa-kaaba' /> Haj Setup Form</span>}
        width={window.innerWidth > 900 ? 800 : window.innerWidth - 50}
        onClose={onClose}
        visible={visible}
        bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
        extra={
          <Space>
            <Button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
            <Button onClick={onClose} type="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Space>
        }
      >
        <Form 
      style={{display: formVisible ? 'block' : 'none'}}
          form={form}
          layout="vertical" 
                onFinish={onFinish}
                onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
                autoComplete="off"
                          
          hideRequiredMark>
            

            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={24}>

                <Form.Item
                  name="packageName"
                  label="Package Name"
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter package name' }]}
                  initialValue={objCounter}
                  
                  >
                  <Input style={{width: '100%'}}
                         maxLength={100}  /> 
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
        </Form>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  )
});


export default AddNew
```

Comment: So you are wanting to update the local state of the child component (`AddNew`) when. button is clicked in the parent component? What value are you wanting to send to `showDrawer`? From what I can tell you enqueue a state update but only send the current state value.

Comment: It's unclear you claim isn't updating. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-not-updating-data-when-passing-from-parent-functional-component-using-r-hm9t7) with the local `objCounter` state updating. Can you update your question to include all relevant code?

Comment: I don't see any ref being used inside child component. Check the react docs to see how to properly use useImperativeHandle and useRef

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV The ref is used in the `useImperativeHandle` hook in the child component.

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, I made few changes at codesandbox pleaes check there is another error

Comment: Thanks Drew its working fine, let me made changes at my code, must be issue on some other side at my code

Comment: Am I understanding your comment that now you see that the state is updating as expected and this question/post can be closed/deleted since unreproducible, and  you've still *some other* issue to track down and ask about?

Comment: Hi Drew, Issue is on ANTD form                 
showing here 
              <input value={objCounter} />

but not showing at initialValue
                <Form.Item
                  name="packageName"
                  label="Package Name"
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter package name' }]}
                  initialValue={objCounter}
                  
                  >
                  <Input style={{width: '100%'}}
                         maxLength={100}  /> 
                </Form.Item>

Comment: Resolved need to set in Input at ANTD form item instead the initialValue

Comment: Does your antd form have only the one input? Where are the `Form` props declared. I think you might have a few options, but we would need to see all of the child component code to see how you are instantiating the `Form` and props.

Comment: No, I am sending object with prop but for the time I am trying to resolve for one input, still issue with antd form Input

Comment: Hi Drew can you please take a look at codesandbox, I have made changes you can see the value can be correct populating in simple input but not in antd form Input.

Answer (score 1):

Since the state updates are working and you are simply wanting to update the form field, you can use the returned `form` reference from the `useForm` hook to update the form state. In this case, update the `packageName` field.

```
const AddNew = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [objCounter, setobjCounter] = useState(13);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [formVisible, setformVisible] = useState(true);
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showDrawer(count) {
      setobjCounter(count);
      setVisible(true);

      form.setFieldsValue({
        packageName: count // <-- update the specific field
      });
    }
  }));

  const onClose = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
});
```

[image: Edit usestate-not-updating-data-when-passing-from-parent-functional-component-using-r (forked)]

Comment: Booooom Booom Great Thanks Drew.

Comment: Yes but one more enhancement if antd form have any method to bind all fields at once, like form.setFieldsValues(props?.editData)... ??? It will be very easy

Comment: Its done too, that's goood, Its Resolved and enhanced tooo.

Comment: @MuhammadFaheemChughtai I'm not very familiar with antd components, but my guess would be that `setFieldValues` takes an object of key-value pairs representing *any* of your fields, by `name` attribute. For example, if you had 2 inputs, `firstName` and `lastName`, then you could conceivably use `setFieldValues({ firstName: 'Drew', lastName: 'Reese' })`.

Comment: Thanks you Drew, seems good now, I am new on ant, I will ask you if any issue, Thanks again.

Comment: yes it was resolved, where i can accept it please?